# Trying to compare input password with the one in database. Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, hash, passwords

Im trying to make a method that allows a user to change password.
Im having trubble comparing the old password thats being entered with the one saved in the database.

This is what ive tried doing:

```
$newHash = Security::hash($this->request->data['User']['old_password'],'sha1', $storedHash);
```

Comment: What version of CakePHP?  The way the Auth component works has significantly changed in 3.0.  For 2.0, you should be comparing what's in the database with `AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['old_password']);`

Comment: I assume the old password is already hashed when stored in the database, so why re-hash it? Are you trying to *change* the hash? Because that's a different story.

Comment: You might want to read/leverage [working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/)